# How can I add line separator between two list items in multi-list?

Tags: codenameone

How can I add line separator between two list items in multi-list..?
And I want to style multi-list also like keeping different colors for multiple items.. Any Help.??

Answer (score 1):

Your question is so broad but I will help you with few guidelines.

Use `MultiButton` as it gives you more control over MultiList. MultiList is for Intermediate and Advance codenameone developers and not beginners.

Then style the `MultiButton` UIID in your **theme.res/GUI Builder** by doing the following:

Open the `MultiButton` UIID and switch to the `Border` tab, Click the **Image Border Wizard*.

Change the Thickness to 2, and `Arc width` + `Arc height` to 1,

Color A = desired background color

Color B = desired background color

Color C = desired line color

Color D = desired line color

Change the line color as desired then switch to `Cut Image` tab.

Set the following:

Top = 19
Bottom = 19
Right = 5
Left = 5

Crop Top = 2
Crop Bottom = 0
Crop Right = 2
Crop Left = 2

Click `Ok` when you're done. Now copy and paste this MultiButton and rename the UIID in the open window and repeat above with a different color. Apply this UIID to your items as required.